# Is there an easy way to compute the jacobian of a normalized vector?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, jacobian

If $x \in \mathbb{R}^3$ I want to compute the jacobian of the following function

$$
f(x) = \frac{x}{\lVert x \rVert }
$$

If I proceed I get a matrix whose elements are

$$
a_{ij} = \begin{cases}
\frac{1}{\lVert x \rVert} - \frac{x_i^2}{\lVert x \rVert^3} & i = j \\
-\frac{x_i x_j}{\lVert x \rVert^3} &i \neq j
\end{cases}
$$

Is this the most compact form?
The derivation is based on the product rule componentwise.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Extending user8469759's comment (and shortening $\nu := f(x)$).

There's even a bit simpler form, namely
\begin{equation}
   \frac{1}{\lVert x \rVert}\left(I - \nu \nu^T \right).
\end{equation}
This also has a geometric interpretation: the mapping
$y \mapsto (I - \nu \nu^T) y$
is a projection to the normal plane of $\nu$, in other words, it removes the component in the direction of the normalized vector $\nu$.

Comment: Can you derive the expression?

Comment: It can be derived from your formula using the bilinearity of $x \cdot x^T$:
\begin{equation}
\frac{x \cdot x^T}{ \lVert x \rVert^2 }
= \lVert x \rVert^{-1} \lVert x \rVert^{-1}(x \cdot x^T)
= (\lVert x \rVert^{-1}x) \cdot (\lVert x \rVert^{-1} x)^T = f(x) \cdot (f(x))^T
\end{equation}

Answer (score 1):

I get the same result:
$$
\begin{align}
J_{ij} 
&= \partial_j \left( \frac{x}{\lVert x \rVert} \right)_i \\
&= \partial_j x_i \left(\sum_k x_k^2\right)^{-1/2} \\
&= \frac{\delta_{ij}}{\lVert x \rVert} + 
x_i \left(-\frac{1}{2}\right) \left(\sum_k x_k^2\right)^{-3/2}(2 x_k \delta_{kj}) \\
&= \frac{\delta_{ij}}{\lVert x \rVert} - \frac{x_i x_j}{\lVert x \rVert^3}
\end{align}
$$

Comment: Maybe an equivalent would be $$\frac{1}{\lVert x \rVert}\left(I - \frac{x \cdot x^T}{\lVert x \rVert^2} \right)$$