# Differential geometry interpretation of a normalized vector

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds

I am trying to understand this [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2882762/is-there-an-easy-way-to-compute-the-jacobian-of-a-normalized-vector) in terms of differential geometry. Since now I have concluded to the following, please verify my thoughts.

1. The normalization function $f(x) = x / ||x||_2$ can be seen as the mapping
   \begin{equation}
   f \colon \mathbb{R}^n/\{0\}\to S^{n-1}.
   \end{equation}
2. The Jacobian of $f$ given by
   \begin{equation}
      J_f = \frac{1}{\lVert x \rVert}\left(I - x x^T / ||x||_2^2 \right)
   \end{equation} can be used to define the differential function
   \begin{equation}
   f_{*,x} \colon T_x\mathbb{R}^n\to T_xS^{n-1}
   \end{equation} at point $p$.

My questions are:

1. Shall we define a $f_{*,x}$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R^n}$?
2. If we apply $x$ on $f_{*,x}$ we obtain the zero vector. Is $x$ thought of as a point, the origin of $T_{x}\mathbb{R}^n$, and thus it is meaningless to apply $x$ in $f_{*,x}$?
3. If we want to apply another vector $v$ should bellong to $T_{x}\mathbb{R}^n$?
4. If yes, then the output is
   \begin{equation}
   f_{*,x}v = \frac{1}{\lVert x \rVert}\left(I - x x^T / ||x||_2^2 \right)v
   \end{equation} Geometrically I know that $P=I - x x^T / ||x||_2^2$ projects any vector to the left null-space of the single column matrix $x$. How can we interpret in this case $J_f$ that has also a scaling factor $1/||x||$ ?
5. How can be apply $f_{*,x}$ in an arbitrary vector $v\in \mathbb{R}^n$? Shall we cover the entire $\mathbb{R}^n$ with tangent planes $T_{x}\mathbb{R}^n$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}^n$? I am thinking that $T_p\mathbb{R}^n$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^n$ but I can not figure it out.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: shouldn't you exclude the case $x=0$?

Comment: To see why the scaling factor is there, draw some similar triangles. A vector tangent to the sphere at $\lambda x$ scales by a factor of $1/\lambda$ when you project to the unit sphere.